# Time zone is not correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I want to get the time zone when a user enters the date & time. I am living in middle europe and we have here in winter UTC+001 and summer time UTC+002. 
The problem is, I've tested that python, for winter and summer, always gives the summer time UTC+002.

Example:

```
import time

a=time.strptime("13 00 00 30 May 2017", "%H %M %S %d %b %Y")
a_s = time.mktime(a) # to convert in seconds
time.localtime(a_s) #local time
Output>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=13, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=150, tm_isdst=1)

time.gmtime(a_s) # UTC time
Output>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=11, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=150, tm_isdst=0)

#Now the Winter
b = time.strptime("13 00 00 20 Dec 2017", "%H %M %S %d %b %Y")
b_s = time.mktime(b)
time.localtime(b_s)
Output>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=13, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=354, tm_isdst=0)

time.gmtime(b_s)
Output>>>time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=12, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=354, tm_isdst=0)

time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %z %Z",a)
Output>>>'13:00:00 +0200 Central European Summer Time'

time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %z %Z",b)
Output>>> '13:00:00 +0200 Central European Summer Time' #Wrong should be +0100 and Central European Time
```

Comment: What's wrong? in the summer it's +0200 and right now (december) it's +0100

Comment: The following is wrong. a is summer and b is winter.                 time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %z %Z",a)
Output>>>'13:00:00 +0200 Central European Summer Time'

time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %z %Z",b)
Output>>> '13:00:00 +0200 Central European Summer Time' #Wrong should be +0100 and Central European Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.strftime('%z %Z', tuple)` returns a string representation of the UTC offset and timezone abbreviation *that your local machine is currently using*. It does not try to figure out what timezone the tuple belongs to.

To do that requires looking up daylight savings time boundaries and the
corresponding utcoffsets for a given timezone. This information is in the [tz
("Olson") database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) and in Python most people delegate this job
to the [pytz module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

```
import time
import datetime as DT
import pytz
FMT = "%H:%M:%S %z %Z"

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
for datestring in ["13 00 00 30 May 2017", "13 00 00 20 Dec 2017"]:
    a = time.strptime(datestring, "%H %M %S %d %b %Y")
    a_s = time.mktime(a)  
    # naive datetimes are not associated to a timezone
    naive_date = DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(a_s)
    # use `tz.localize` to make naive datetimes "timezone aware"
    timezone_aware_date = tz.localize(date, is_dst=None)
    print(timezone_aware_date.strftime(FMT))
```

prints

```
13:00:00 +0200 CEST
13:00:00 +0100 CET
```